# Column chart, tootip is displayed incorrectly

Tags: highcharts

I have a simple column chart with three series:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Chart'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['']
        },

        series: [{
            name: "Test1",
            data: [30]
        },
        {
            data: [60]
        },
        {
            data: [10]
        },        
    ]
    });
});
```

But when chart is rendered, series tooltip is displayed incorrectly (not centered) when mouse is above some bar:

[image: Example]

What am I doing wrong?

Here is JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cbhe9x17/

Comment: set useHTML as true. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cbhe9x17/8/, in other cases use [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) to modify content of tooltip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason behind this collapse in tooltip is, you have made categories as follows in your code

```
xAxis: {
            categories: ['']
        },
```

By default, categories & series data will be displayed in tooltip.

To get proper tooltip, you can provide proper categories values or you can use formatter.

```
 xAxis: {
            categories: ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3']
        },
```

[Check this too :)](http://jsfiddle.net/cbhe9x17/2/)

Comment: Thanks, I need empty category, so I was missing formatter setting:

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<span style="color:' + this.color + ';">●</span> ' + this.series.name + ": <b>" + this.y + "</b>";
            },
        },

Answer (score 0):

Highchart's tooltip by default placed in proper location. but in your case you are setting categories to empty. remove this :

```
   xAxis: {
        categories: ['']
    }
```

working fiddle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cbhe9x17/3/)

in other way [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/cbhe9x17/4/)